# Yii Framework Post and comments associated

Tags: ajax, yii, rendering

I'm new in Yii Framework and I would like to render the commments associated to a given post.
I tried to find solution but until now, I cannot figure out how to do it.

I have a list of posts and when I click a link I want to list the associated comments without refreshing all the page.

To be clear,   I have the following

**Post 1**

My post 1 description    ..........................       **Comment (1)**

**Post 2**

My post 2 description    ..........................       **Comment (3)**

**Post 3**

My post 3 description    ..........................       **Comment (5)**

---

### and when I click to comment (3) of the post 2, I want the following

My post 1 description    ..........................       **Comment (1)**

**Post 2**

My post 2 description    ..........................       **Comment (3)**

Comment 1

Comment 2

Comment 3

**Post 3**

My post 3 description    ..........................       **Comment (5)**

...

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CHtml::ajaxLink()](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh1)

There are plenty of examples on the linked article to populate a div, under the post.

Comment: Do you have any interesting link ?  I cannot found out

Comment: Did you checked the link that I posted? It's linked under: CHtml::ajaxLink()